# Ethernet isn't working on Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ethernet

I'm setting up a server with Ubuntu Server. I'm using a seperate machine to set this up as the server I have doesn't have any display out. I've put the hard drive in another computer and are working from there. Initially, everything worked but I put it in the server to see the ethernet not working. It also doesn't work on my laptop, which I have the hard drive hooked up to now.

Here's the ifconfig output with the Ethernet in:

```
lo: flags-73<UP, LOOPBACK, RUNNING> mtu 65536 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 sinet61 prefixlen 128 scopeid ox10 cost> loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) RX packets 180 bytes 11976 (11.9 KB) RX errors 0 dropped o overruns 0 frame o TX packets 180 bytes 11976 (11.9 KB) TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions
```

EDIT: /etc/netplan has one file named 50-cloud-init.yaml Here is its output:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s31f6:
            addresses: [] 
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Here is the output of sudo lshw -C network:

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:ad:d9:fb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 60:a4:4c:71:ff:10
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

Here is the output of ifconfig:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3056  bytes 184872 (184.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3056  bytes 184872 (184.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that those 2 outputs were from the laptop (I'm booting from the hard drive)
Last edit: I honestly don't know if this server is booting at this point, it doesn't help that there's no video/serial output. I guess I'll have to buy a VGA port from eBay (HP Mediaserver EX490).

Comment: Edit your question and show me the name/content of any .yaml files in `/etc/netplan`. Show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig`. We'll have to configure netplan for the ethernet devices on your real server.

Comment: I need to hear more about your server config. Do you have a console device, be it serial, or otherwise? How do you plan on booting the server?

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question with those outputs. There is no serial, only USB ports, an eSATA, and the ethernet. I'm assuming the server will boot as this will be the only boot device.

Comment: The .yaml file is wrong. That's why it doesn't work on your laptop, let alone on the server. Do my answer exactly as I specify, and lets see if we can get it to work on your laptop first. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I just noticed that your .yaml file is incomplete. Edit as I show in my **Update #1** in my answer.

Comment: Status please. Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 0):

The ethernet hardware in the server, the other computer and the laptop are undoubtedly different. Because of persistent interface naming, they also likely have different designations. For instance, the ethernet interface may be named enp0s25 in one; enp0s12 in another and eno1 in another.

As a consequence, installing Ubuntu server on one computer and then changing the harddrive to the server without any amendments to netplan is unlikely to ever work, as you’ve seen.

Troubleshooting requires finding out the exact interface name in the server and then setting up netplan accordingly.

I am unaware of any method to do so without a display and keyboard. Once set up, however, the server may be rebooted without them. Thereafter, administration can take place with ssh.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard, as long as you can get to the server, with SSH or whatever. You have to be able to identify the proper network interfaces, and write a /etc/netplan/*.yaml file, and a couple of sudo commands.

Comment: But in order to ssh to the server, don't you need a network connection, @heynnema ??

Comment: Good point. I'd like to think that there's a console device on this server, be it serial, or whatever. Maybe not. How would you boot the server if there wasn't something?

Comment: On his other machine, we can tweak the kernel params with "net.ifnames=0", assume that the ethernet device will be called eth0, write/edit the .yaml file and sudo netplan generate/apply, move the hard disk to the server, and hope for the best.

Comment: @heynnema That's probably his best shot. If it works, I will fall off my chair!

Comment: Yes, we need to hear more from the OP about his server config. Adjust your chair now :-)

Comment: I think that's the only slim chance, assuming that no display is at all possible. A temporary display would be most helpful @heynnema

Comment: I'm using a HP Mediasmart server that is totally headless, no VGA or anything, which is a pain. I've been using [this guide](https://blog.fosketts.net/2017/07/21/recalling-hp-mediasmart-server-active-duty/), which assumes that the interface is called enp0s4 @heynnema

Comment: Also notifying @chili555 , check my above comment :)

Comment: @UnicornsOnLSD yes, but after using the `net.ifnames=0` parameter, it'll probably be called eth0, which is a much better guess than enp0s4 from another guide on the Internet. Try my answer and report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

On your build machine, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `net.ifnames=0` in either:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then edit the .yaml file in `/etc/netplan`, and make sure that the ethernet device specified is `eth0`. Then do:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Configure SSH to be able to log in. Try rebooting and trying this out on your build machine. This should work if your build machine's ethernet device is `eth0` after the grub change.

Shut down, and move the device to your server and keep your fingers crossed that the ethernet will come up and work!

**Update #1:**

I just noticed that your basic `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` is not complete. Here's how it should look after an edit...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Then:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
```