# Netplan Different Machine

Tags: server, 18.10, netplan

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on a HP X310 headless server with no VGA port. Due to this I am unable to install directly on the machine. I have a system with similar specs and same networking chip that I am able to install on, then swap the hard drive over. This appears to work, but I cannot get the network port working. I know this because I am able to blind type 'shutdown now' and it will work.

Is there a way in netplan to force the system to update the network card on the next boot, or is there a way to blind type a command that would make netplan configured the new network port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

**Install** the hard disk into your working server system.

**Edit** `/etc/default/grub`. Find the line, near the top, that includes "quiet splash" and add "net.ifnames=0". This will make the network devices have standard, old school, device names. Your ethernet device will almost certainly become `eth0` instead of some strange variable name like `ens01p01`. Then do `sudo update-grub`. Then reboot.

**Edit** `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` and change the **ethernets:** device definition from `ens01p01` to `eth0`. Then `sudo netplan --debug generate` and `sudo netplan apply`.

**Reboot** the computer and use `ifconfig` to confirm that the ethernet device is `eth0`. If not, you'll need to modify the .yaml file indicated earlier.

**Move** the hard disk to the primary server, and it should all work.

Comment: That worked great! After the first reboot the network port didn't show at all in ifconfig, but after edititing the *.yaml file as you suggested and rebooting it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 FYI... from another question that we worked on together... get ready to "pick yourself up off of the floor"... this method does work! We had never received closure on the other question.

Comment: @chili555 FYI #2... for reference, it was https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089580/ethernet-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts/1089618#1089618

Comment: @heynnema I am always happy to be enlightened. I hope to learn more every day. Thanks for the heads up. A very clever solution!